# Use Conda-Pack packages in machine with no internet connection

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am trying to move my anaconda environment from a PC with internet connection to the one with no internet access. I am using conda pack package in Anaconda and I successfully unpack the packages in target machine and python and all the packages are imported just fine using cmd.

However I am wondering how I can do the same thing in Anaconda prompt? (I am using Windows 10 OS).
When I type in anaconda prompt nothing will happen.

```
activate.bat 
conda-unpack
```

The above two commands work fine in cmd. The instruction in the website is for Linux.

How can I use the packages and Python I moved to the target machine. How can I connect the VS code to this environment?
If I want to use the Jupyter notebook, should I install it on the source machine and then use the conda pack again and unpack it in the target machine?